# 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' firebase cloud function realtime database react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

writing my first cloud base function but running into the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded at ProactiveRefresh.hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>)`.

I'm simply changing the username if the logged in user.

code in FE is as follows:

```
const saveUser = httpsCallable(
    functions,
    'changeUserData'
);

const testUpdateProfile = async (
    username: string,
) => {
    await saveUser(
        {
            userId: auth.currentUser,
            username: username,
        }
    );
}
```

The functions is a export from another component that looks like:

```
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const functions = getFunctions(
    app,
    'europe-west1'
);
```

The cloud functions looks like this:

```
exports.changeUserData = functions.region("europe-west1")
    .https.onCall((data, context) => {
      const userId = context.auth.uid;
      const newData = {username: data.username};

      // Check that the authenticated user's UID matches the userId property
      if (userId !== data.userId) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            "permission-denied",
            "You can only modify your own data.",
        );
      }
      return admin.database().ref("/users/${userId}")
          .set(newData).then(
              () => {
                console.log(`user ${userId} updated`);

                return {username: data.username};
              },
          ).catch((error) => {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
                "aborted",
                error.code + error.message,
            );
          });
    });
```

I've looked on similar issues on here but most seem to be related to circular dependencies in their components. I'm quite certain this is not the case in here as i debugged and the `saveUser` only gets called once.

Comment: Are you sure that `auth.currentUser` returns a user uid (in `saveUser()` function)? (and not the entire `User` Object?)

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Nope i was not! looks to be the fix. Could you add this as answer? I'll mark it as is. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in

```
await saveUser(
    {
        userId: auth.currentUser,
        username: username,
    }
);
```

`auth` is the reference to the Firebase Auth service, then `auth.currentUser` is a [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user?hl=en) object and not the user’s uid. You therefore need to do `userId: auth.currentUser.uid`.